# Gnome shell open folder with alt+f2 broken

Tags: linux, gnome, debian-stretch

I'm on Debian 9 with Gnome 3.22.2, and out of nowhere the alt+f2 command runner stopped working as it should. When I type the path to a folder, instead of showing it on nautilus as it always did, it opens the folder on visual studio code. I didn't even install VSCode recently, everything worked fine until today. The only significant (maybe) change that I made recently was installing menulibre to edit a couple of menu entries, but even after doing that I don'r remember the command runner being broken.

Any help would be appreciated, I use the command runner non-stop all day so I really need it to work

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` VSCode was set as the default application for opening folders. How did it end up that way is a mystery to me, but deleting that line fixed my problem